# pycairo. Не удается сделать surface из изображения

Tags: python, изображения, pycairo

Пытался вставить изображение из BytesIO, что бы не выгонять в файл. В png и в base64 преобразуется корректно для использования в svg, например. Но cairo выдает ошибку.

```
bytes = BytesIO()
img.save(bytes)

imgsf = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png(bytes)
cr.set_source_surface(imgsf, 0, 0)
cr.paint()
```

> cairo.IOError: error while reading from input stream

При этом если гнать через файл, а не через BytesIO то всё работает нормально.

Если делаю bytes.getvalue() то

> ValueError: embedded null byte

Попробовал что то еще поплясать, плюнул.
Дальше - узнал что cairo умеет в PIL (или из PIL). Вот казалось бы спасение ([Integration with other Libraries. Pillow (PIL) & Cairo](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#pillow-pil-cairo)). Ведь либа изначально и дает PIL. Ок, пробуем. Копирую код, правлю ссылки, работает, но что то с картинкой не то происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Если сделать png то это обычный квадратный qr-код, а тут вот так.

Попробовал методом научного.. изменить какие то параметры, картинка становится ЧБ например, или еще какие метаморфозы с ней происходят, но так и остается такой суженной.

Хорошо. Там есть еще вариант c NumPy. И либа умеет делать некую матрицу (что то вроде массива булов) и cairo вроде как готов принимать такое ([Creating an ImageSurface from a NumPy array](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#numpy-imagesurface)). Не стал глубоко вникать, попытался в лоб взять примерами оттуда и оттуда, скрестить и... конечно тоже не вышло. Выдал

> TypeError: buffer is not long enough

Ради спортивного попытался воспроизвести чисто кайровский пример, получилась какая то белиберда разноцветная.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пришел к выводу что Cairo - это не для слабонервных.

Помогите разобраться с этим чудом. Как этой кайрой нормально вставить картинку не из файла?

> Век живи, век учись. Оказывается pillow тоже может рисовать! Меняю лопату, иду копать туда.

Pillow - это оказалось слишком "растрово".
Пока прорабатываю варианты возвращения к связке SVGWriter+CairoPDF, но с добавлением шрифтовой тулзы из cairo или pillow.
Либо остановлюсь на варианте с cairo, но буду гнать через файл. Не понимаю что за баг у кайро.
Пока не знаю что из всего этого менее ресурсонакладно.

Answer (score 0):

Создал ишью на гитхабе ([тыц](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/issues/245)), ответили что нужно добавить
`bytes.seek(0)`
и всё получится.

Итого:

```
bytes = BytesIO()
img.save(bytes)

bytes.seek(0) #Вот тут

imgsf = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png(bytes)
cr.set_source_surface(imgsf, 0, 0)
cr.paint()
```

Всё получилось. Это работает.